# Node.js Arguments to path.join must be strings but arguments are a path

Tags: javascript, node.js, types, sequelize.js

I'm using the path module in Node.js version v0.10.36. It works on my laptop in Node.js version v0.10.30. I am basically passing a string contained in an object with one of the return values from a function handled by Sequelize that fetches from a MySQL Database. If I switch out the path.join function to a regular path+'/'+file it works fine. However, for some reason path.join keeps throwing errors in the program. I added some console.logs to illustrate my point. The errors come from these lines:

```
console.log( this.recordingRow.get( 'id' ) );
console.log( config.path.audio );
var filepath = path.join( config.path.audio, this.recordingRow.get( 'id' ) );
```

But here is the output:

```
241
/home/sonar/sonar/files/audio

Unhandled rejection TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at path.js:360:15                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    at Array.filter (native)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    at Stream.startSonarData (/home/sonar/sonar/inc/streams/stream.js:148:22)                                                                                                                                                                
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sonar/sonar/inc/streams/stream.js:74:8)                                                                                                                                                                     
    at Object.tryCatcher (/home/sonar/sonar/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:24:31)                                                                                                                              
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/sonar/sonar/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:452:31)                                                                                                          
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/home/sonar/sonar/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:530:18)                                                                                                                   
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/sonar/sonar/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:646:14)                                                                                                                    
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/sonar/sonar/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:177:16)                                                                                                                            
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/sonar/sonar/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:187:10)                                                                                                                           
    at Async.drainQueues (/home/sonar/sonar/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)                                                                                                                             
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

Comment: Well, the error is pretty obvious. One of the arguments is not a string. The first one appears to be a number.

Comment: Okay I will. Can you typecast in JavaScript to a string? Is that even possible?

Comment: simply concat `+''` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error is pretty obvious. One of the arguments is not a string. The first one appears to be a number. Just convert it to a string first, e.g. via `String`:

```
path.join(a, String(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Felix, your second argument is not a string but a number. There are two ways to typecast a number to a String :-

- path.join( config.path.audio, ~~(this.recordingRow.get( 'id' )) );
- path.join( config.path.audio, String(this.recordingRow.get( 'id' )) );